# Redirect the table generated from Beeline to text file without the grid (Shell Script)

Tags: bash, shell, hive, beeline

I am currently trying to find a way to redirect the standard output from beeline shell to text file without the grid. The biggest problem I am facing right now is that my columns have negative values and when I'm using regex to remove the '-', it is affecting the column values.

```
+-------------------+
|       col         |
+-------------------+
| -100              |
|  22               |
| -120              |
| -190              |
| -800              |
+-------------------+
```

Here's what I'm doing:

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default \
  -e "SELECT * FROM $db.$tbl;" | sed 's/\+//g' | sed 's/\-//g' | sed 's/\|//g' > table.txt
```

I am trying to clean this file so I can read all the data into a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming all your data has the same pattern , where no significant '-' are wrapped in '+' :

```
[root@machine]# cat boo
+-------------------+
|       col         |
+-------------------+
| -100              |
|  22               |
| -120              |
| -190              |
| -800              |
+-------------------+

[root@machine]# cat boo |  sed 's/\+-*+//g' | sed 's/\--//g' | sed 's/|//g'

       col

 -100
  22
 -120
 -190
 -800
```